# DataTables not recognizing data

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to insert data into my DataTable.

I have the following code:

DataTable:

```
<table id="ladder" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Team Name</th>
            <th>W - L</th>
            <th>Strk</th>
            <th>Exp</th>
            <th>Level</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="ladder_stats">

     </tbody>
</table>
```

The JQuery:

```
function fillLadder(place, name, w, l, strk, exp, lvl, id, ladder) {

    $('<tr><td>' + place + '</td><td><a href="/team?id=' + id + '&l=' + ladder + '">' + name + '</a></td><td>' + w + ' - ' + l + '</td><td>' + strk + '</td><td>' + exp + '</td><td>' + lvl + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#ladder_stats');
}

function refreshLadder() {

    var ladder = $.urlParam('l');

    $.ajax({ 

     url: '/data/ladder_stats.php',
        data: {l: ladder},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(json) {

            console.log(json);

            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) { 
                fillLadder(json[i].place, json[i].name, json[i].wins, json[i].losses, json[i].strk, json[i].exp, json[i].level, json[i].id, ladder);
            }

        },
        error: function(ts) {
            console.log("Error: " + ts.responseText);
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    refreshLadder();
    $('#ladder').DataTable();
    $('#match_finder').DataTable();
});
```

As you can see from the code, I'm inserting the data into the table before I load the `DataTable()` function. Unfortunately DataTables does not recognize the data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, I believe it is due to the timing.  Your ajax call could take a while, moving the datatables call to the success should work.  Updated to something like this.

```
function fillLadder(place, name, w, l, strk, exp, lvl, id, ladder) {

    $('<tr><td>' + place + '</td><td><a href="/team?id=' + id + '&l=' + ladder + '">' + name + '</a></td><td>' + w + ' - ' + l + '</td><td>' + strk + '</td><td>' + exp + '</td><td>' + lvl + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#ladder_stats');
}

function refreshLadder() {

    var ladder = $.urlParam('l');

    $.ajax({ 

     url: '/data/ladder_stats.php',
        data: {l: ladder},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(json) {

            console.log(json);

            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) { 
                fillLadder(json[i].place, json[i].name, json[i].wins, json[i].losses, json[i].strk, json[i].exp, json[i].level, json[i].id, ladder);
            }

            //Rows created, now we can make tables
            $('#ladder').DataTable();
            $('#match_finder').DataTable();

        },
        error: function(ts) {
            console.log("Error: " + ts.responseText);
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    refreshLadder();
});
```

Comment: That's it!! Thanks a lot. I was struggling with this for a while already :)

Comment: A simple `columns` section would have solved that quite easy.  Parsing JSON and inserting table elements manually is exactly what should be avoided with dataTables. The above solution does not solve the problem which is a general misunderstanding of how to use dataTables, it just fix  the misunderstanding so it seems to kind of work...OP will face problems if he try to reload data, which I highly suspect is the purpose of `refreshLadder()` ...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this:

```
function refreshLadder() {

    var ladder = $.urlParam('l');

    $.ajax({ 

     url: '/data/ladder_stats.php',
        data: {l: ladder},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(json) {

            console.log(json);

            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) { 
                fillLadder(json[i].place, json[i].name, json[i].wins, json[i].losses, json[i].strk, json[i].exp, json[i].level, json[i].id, ladder);
            }

            $('#ladder').DataTable(); //initiating it after appening all the rows
            $('#match_finder').DataTable();

        },
        error: function(ts) {
            console.log("Error: " + ts.responseText);
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    refreshLadder();

});
```